# Adding forced preview to node and change submit button value in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, content-type

This question is two-fold:

1. Is there any way to force a user to first preview a SPECIFIC node before submitting it? i.e. Not all nodes using /admin/content/node-settings ... but only ONE specific node.
2. Is there any way to change the labels to instead of saying "submit" and "preview", rather say "Process" and "Review"?

Answer (score 3):

The basic answer to both questions is [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6). You'd need to check the `$form_id` parameter to determine if you are on a node edit form (they get the id `[contenttype]_node_form`, see the first line of the example implementation on the API documentation page for a way to trigger for all content types).

For your need 1, you'd check `$node->nid` to see if it is your specific node. If so, you'd alter the forms submit button definitions '#access' entry to disable it, if you're not on a preview page (see the [`node_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_form/6) function from the node module on how Drupal does this - pretty far to the end of the function).

For your need 2, you'd simply change the '#value' entries of the submit and preview button definitions in the $form array.

Answer (score 1):

You can change whether previewing before posting is required at `/admin/content/node-settings` (Drupal 6).

As for changing the button text, you'd probably have to do that with either a code hook on the form, or somewhere in your theme.

Comment: Is ther any way to force it for only ONE node type?

Comment: In Drupal core? Not to my knowledge. Someone may have written a module to do it though.